# Redirecting to other domain with parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the initial url:

`http://example.net/any/number/folders/param1/param2/value2/value1`

and this is the url we need to be mapped to:

`http://example.com/any/number/folders/param1.php?param1=value1&param2=value2`

The script param1.php is under directory param1 and both exist.

I have these rules but don't work. Usually get a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /param1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /param1
RewriteRule ^(.*)(param1)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/$2.php?$2=$5&$2=$3 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I have been trying to make it work for hours and also searched for something similar. At this point I am not even sure if it is possible.

Any suggestion or solution will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made some minor adjustments, you may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /param1
RewriteRule ^(.*)(param1)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$  http://example.com/$1$2.php?$2=$5&$3=$4 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am testing your answer in a tester site but got a strange character instead of `&`. Everything else seems to be working.

Comment: In this case you have to test it in a real server. The tester site is of great help but still have limitations.